# AWS ELB HTTPS to HTTP Using Spring-Boot MVC Login Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, ssl-certificate

I am using Spring-Boot running in an AWS instance with an Elastic Load Balancer.  I am using Spring MVC with login security with the server port is set to 8080.  I have installed an AWS generated certificate with the correct web name, test.mydomain.com, in the ELB.  The ELB listeners are set up for port 80 HTTP >> 8080 HTTP and 443 HTTPS >> 8080 HTTP.  Here is my WebSecurityConfig class,

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDS;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        // Allows access for .css, .js, and .images files
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();

        // Access management for all other requests
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDS).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDS;

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }


}
```

When I access the home page, https://test.mydomian.com/home, everything is fine and the page is secure.  I am certain the certificate is working.  I tried using curl -vk https:test.mydomain.com/home and verified that the certificate is working.  When I click login, the page reverts to HTTP (Unsecure) and all other pages going forward are HTTP.

I tried the following experiment with the ELB.  I eliminated the port 80 listener so that I only had a one listener on 443 -- 443 HTTPS >> HTTP 8080.  Again, I logged in to https://test.mydomain.com/home and the page was secure.  When I clicked login, the browser failed to find the page.  I noticed the browser address bar had http://test.mydomain.com/login.  Since there was no listener for port 80 the request failed.  Why is my login page trying to access port 80?  In my application.properties page I have have server.port = 8080.  It makes no sense to me that the login page is reverting to port 80.  Anyone have any ideas? I have seen a lot of posts talking about login ELB redirects causing a lot of Spring MVC ELB problems.  Could this be my problem?

Comment: Would you consider using an ALB? This problem is solved much easier that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your ELB will act as a proxy you'll have to configure Spring (and the server you're running on) to use the forward headers by setting `server.use-forward-headers` to `true` in your `application.properties`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.21.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server for more information.

**Edit:** As of **Spring Boot 2.2** the `server.use-forward-headers` property has been deprecated in favor for `server.forward-headers-strategy`. See  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-22

Comment: Awesum-Sauce -- I added "server.use-forward-headers = true" to  application.properties and it worked perfectly!  Your url pointer was an excellent description of what is going on.

Comment: I am stuck again in the second part of this problem.  I am trying to redirect all port 80 requests to 443.  The redirects are working fine but I am always going to my login page instead of my /home page.  Here is the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271814/aws-elb-spring-mvc-https-redirect-home-keeps-going-to-login) for the stackoverflow question.  It looks like I am having redirect problems again.  Can you take a look?

Comment: I added `server.forward-headers-strategy` and set the value to `native`. It worked as I intended. Thank you!